# How to copy one object to another variable without passing refrence in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have one object

```
var a = {b:{c:{d:{e:1}}}}
```

I want to copy that object to another variable b, without passing a reference, so I try spread operator

```
var b = {...a}
```

It is not removing reference at a deep level, as I change the value in the object "a" it also changes the value in the object "b"

```
    a.b.c.d.e = 2
    console.log(b.b.c.d.e)
```

it give output 2 instead of 1

```js
var a = {b:{c:{d:{e:1}}}};
var b = {...a};
a.b.c.d.e = 2;
console.log(b.b.c.d.e)
document.write(b.b.c.d.e)
```

How can I handle this issue

Answer (score 0):

I've always done this to copy JSON objects. Works great IMO there may be a better way out there.

```
var a = {b:{c:{d:{e:1}}}};
var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
a.b.c.d.e = 2;
console.log(b.b.c.d.e)
document.write(b.b.c.d.e)
```

Comment: `stringy` should be `stringify`. Also this approach fails for dates, undefineds, regular expressions, functions, etc. etc. Use with care!

Comment: Thanks for catching that grammar mishap. It is fixed now in the answer. I know the undefined value will just not exist when it gets parse, but when checking against to see if a value is stored, it returns the same; granted it does lose the key value if that is checked against. 

Also, you don't lose dates, just the date object itself, however, regular expressions are just dropped.